# Git pull unable to update local ref

Tags: windows, git, shell, cmd

I have something weird since we started using sub modules for git. **I'm on Windows 10** and use either Tortoise git or Powershell or cmd or the Linux command interpreter.

Whenever I try to pull a sub module, I get something like this:

> ```
> PS
> D:\repositories\git\ProjectAlice\ProjectAliceSkills\PublishedSkills\AliceCore>
> git pull error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.35>=1.0.0-a4': Unable
> to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.35>=1.0.0-a4.lock':
> Invalid argument From
> https://github.com/project-alice-assistant/skill_AliceCore  ! [new
> tag]         1.0.35>=1.0.0-a4 -> 1.0.35>=1.0.0-a4  (unable to update
> local ref) error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.36>=1.0.0-a5': Unable
> to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.36>=1.0.0-a5.lock':
> Invalid argument  ! [new tag]         1.0.36>=1.0.0-a5 ->
> 1.0.36>=1.0.0-a5  (unable to update local ref) error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.37>=1.0.0-a5': Unable to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.37>=1.0.0-a5.lock':
> Invalid argument  ! [new tag]         1.0.37>=1.0.0-a5 ->
> 1.0.37>=1.0.0-a5  (unable to update local ref) error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.38>=1.0.0-a5': Unable to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.38>=1.0.0-a5.lock':
> Invalid argument  ! [new tag]         1.0.38>=1.0.0-a5 ->
> 1.0.38>=1.0.0-a5  (unable to update local ref) error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.39>=1.0.0-a5': Unable to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.39>=1.0.0-a5.lock':
> Invalid argument  ! [new tag]         1.0.39>=1.0.0-a5 ->
> 1.0.39>=1.0.0-a5  (unable to update local ref) error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.40>=1.0.0-a5': Unable to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.40>=1.0.0-a5.lock':
> Invalid argument  ! [new tag]         1.0.40>=1.0.0-a5 ->
> 1.0.40>=1.0.0-a5  (unable to update local ref) error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.42>=1.0.0-a5': Unable to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.42>=1.0.0-a5.lock':
> Invalid argument  ! [new tag]         1.0.42>=1.0.0-a5 ->
> 1.0.42>=1.0.0-a5  (unable to update local ref) PS D:\repositories\git\ProjectAlice\ProjectAliceSkills\PublishedSkills\AliceCore>
> git pull error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.35>=1.0.0-a4': Unable
> to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.35>=1.0.0-a4.lock':
> Invalid argument From
> https://github.com/project-alice-assistant/skill_AliceCore  ! [new
> tag]         1.0.35>=1.0.0-a4 -> 1.0.35>=1.0.0-a4  (unable to update
> local ref) error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.36>=1.0.0-a5': Unable
> to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.36>=1.0.0-a5.lock':
> Invalid argument  ! [new tag]         1.0.36>=1.0.0-a5 ->
> 1.0.36>=1.0.0-a5  (unable to update local ref) error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.37>=1.0.0-a5': Unable to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.37>=1.0.0-a5.lock':
> Invalid argument  ! [new tag]         1.0.37>=1.0.0-a5 ->
> 1.0.37>=1.0.0-a5  (unable to update local ref) error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.38>=1.0.0-a5': Unable to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.38>=1.0.0-a5.lock':
> Invalid argument  ! [new tag]         1.0.38>=1.0.0-a5 ->
> 1.0.38>=1.0.0-a5  (unable to update local ref) error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.39>=1.0.0-a5': Unable to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.39>=1.0.0-a5.lock':
> Invalid argument  ! [new tag]         1.0.39>=1.0.0-a5 ->
> 1.0.39>=1.0.0-a5  (unable to update local ref) error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.40>=1.0.0-a5': Unable to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.40>=1.0.0-a5.lock':
> Invalid argument  ! [new tag]         1.0.40>=1.0.0-a5 ->
> 1.0.40>=1.0.0-a5  (unable to update local ref) error: cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/1.0.42>=1.0.0-a5': Unable to create
> 'D:/repositories/git/ProjectAlice/ProjectAliceSkills/.git/modules/PublishedSkills/skill_AliceCore/refs/tags/1.0.42>=1.0.0-a5.lock':
> Invalid argument  ! [new tag]         1.0.42>=1.0.0-a5 ->
> 1.0.42>=1.0.0-a5  (unable to update local ref)
> ```

So, something to do with locked references. The annoying bit is that **when I do the same git pull through the Linux command interpreter**, well, it just works...... Where Tortoise git, cmd or Powershell fails with the mentioned error.

I did update git today to be sure, I did try all the prune suggestions I found on that problem, nothing solves it. Well, use the Linux Command Interpreter then they say! Well, unfortunately, there's a ton of sub modules....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is likely the *names of the tags* here:

> ```
>  ! [new tag] 1.0.35>=1.0.0-a4 -> 1.0.35>=1.0.0-a4
> ```

This shows you that, on *their* computer (no doubt running Linux), *they* have a Git tag named `1.0.35>=1.0.0-a4`.  *Your* Git, running on your computer, decided to create a tag with the same name.  (That's the basic idea behind tags: that, unlike *branch* names, everyone should share the same names.  So if they make a tag `X` in their Git, your Git will copy that tag, and its stored hash ID, to your Git, also calling it `X`.  Compare this to branch names: if they make a *branch* named `X`, your Git will *rename* this and call it `origin/X`.)

To do so, your Git is attempting to create local file system files with this string as part of the file's name.  Your *computer* refuses to do that for some reason—probably rejecting the `>` character.  See [Bret Cameron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57507333/1256452) to [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1976007/1256452)

One solution to this is to tell your Git *not* to attempt to copy their tags at all: add `--no-tags` to your `git fetch` or `git pull` command.  A better one is to get your colleagues / co-workers to stop using such characters in *any* names.

Comment: Yep, you were correct, thank you so much for bringing it to my attention! I've rewritten all tags on every submodules with a little script

Comment: What if it happens with a new branch? I'm getting `! [new branch] user/con -> origin/user/con (unable to update local ref)` because `con` is not allowed as a filename on Windows. Any flags to overcome this?

Comment: @ShlomoGottlieb: no: just change the branch name. (There's no need to use the same branch name in any two repositories, except for human preferences / sanity. In this case Windows forces insanity.) Since they have the `con` name and you can't make the `origin/user/con` name at all, you'll have to `git fetch origin user/con:refs/remotes/origin/user-con` or something like that, which will be a pain in the butt, but will work.

Comment: To restore sanity, ask them to change their branch name. In the meantime, consider making this a single-branch clone or otherwise futzing with the default fetch refspecs.